# Disable OLE control toolbar item

Tags: adobe, powerbuilder

I'm running PowerBuilder 12.6 and I have a PDF OLE object which is opened from the powershell script:

```
lb = ole_1.object.LoadFile(is_file_name)
```

When the PDF file is opened, I want to be able to disable the `SAVE` and `PRINT` button in the PDF document.

Is there any Adobe api's that can be used from PowerShell script to enable/disable an icon on the toolbar?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You can hide/show the toolbar with `setShowToolbar(none On: WordBool)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.
However, I do not need to hide the entire toolbar, but disable only the "SAVE" and "Print" option.
Also, I need to block the user save using the context menu or shortcuts.

Comment: You can secure the pdf file (password protect) this will prevent the document from being printed. Below is a link to adobe to secure pdf documents. I am pretty sure the open source versions will have a similar feature.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Acrobat/8.0w/Professional/help.html?content=WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7e04.html